# How to tell if geth is snap syncing?

Tags: go-ethereum

I started geth with full syncing (and synced 14M blocks) and later realized I can use snap syncing. I just restarted geth with `--syncmode=snap` but I can't tell from the logs if geth has switched to snap syncing.

I have two questions:

1. Does geth support switching from full sync to snap sync? If not, should I wipe my currently synced db and start from scratch with snap sync?
2. Does geth output specific logs indicating that it's snap syncing?